# PHP & Mysql Not ordered correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have latest MySQL version (5.5) and this is the screenshot of `groupid` field

I didn't touch anything yet, but some cells are not ordered correctly like this

---

[image]

---

But if I click `groupid` name in the top, it will ordered correctly like this:

---

[image]

---

Below PHP code output is like first screenshot above, that are not ordered correctly. Please help how to make the output ordered correctly, like it is displayed in the second screenshot above,

Maybe add code like this : `order by id asc`, but which is the right place to add it below?

```
$group_ids = explode(" ", $options['groupchoice_ids']);
$groupsql = "SELECT id, title FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "thegroup WHERE";
$first = true;

foreach($group_ids as $value)
    {
    if (!$first)
        {
        $groupsql = $groupsql . " OR ";
        }
      else
        {
        $first = false;
        }

    $groupsql = $groupsql . " id = '" . $value . "' ";
    }

$kh_optionsgroup = '<select name = "accounttype">';
$checksec = $db->query_read($groupsql);

if ($db->num_rows($checksec))
    {
    while ($lboard = $db->fetch_array($checksec))
        {
        $kh_optionsgroup = $kh_optionsgroup . "<option value
    ='" . $lboard['id'] . "'>" . $lboard['title'] . "</option>";
        }
    }

$verifystring = '$human_verify';
$kh_optionsgroup = $kh_optionsgroup . "</select>";
```

Comment: How do you even read your own code with that type of formatting?

Comment: If you look at my answer, I actually edited your query there. Copy paste the one from my answer to replace your one and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your query, you need to set an order, like so:

```
$groupsql="SELECT id, title FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "thegroup WHERE"; 
$first=true;    
foreach($group_ids as $value){
    if(!$first){ 
        $groupsql = $groupsql." OR "; 
    }else{
        $first = false; 
    } 
    $groupsql = $groupsql." id = '".$value."' ORDER BY groupid ASC";
}
```

> ORDER BY id ASC

This will make the query return its results in ascending order from the groupid column. Simply change ASC to DESC if you want it to go descendinng (high->low).

Comment: How do you know the OP using this query?